# Which search engine spiders execute javascript?

Tags: javascript, search, web-crawler, bots

I just come across a issue with the Google spider called "Google Web Preview".  Apparently it is executing javascript.  What I am curious about is what other online bots run JS when they spider/look at a page.  Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: Assume they all do. (So the technique of creating an email address for display using Javascript to avoid spam spider bots is no longer useful.)

Comment: I'm still curious.... what was the issue you encountered?

Comment: One huge issue is that I run some analytics on my pages.  The analytics code that I run is getting executed by the Google Web Preview bot which is creating phantom page views.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an answer regarding `Google`'s practice](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript) on this subject over at the [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I suppose the issue is how to find out if the google bot is actually executing code to figure out what it does or if it is just parsing it and running some checks for common things.  Anyone have any insight or am I stuck on the outside of the Google black-box?